# For Loop Cells(i,j) Speed

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I need to fill specific cells in an Excel Worksheet using an Access Database. I only have to fill in specific cells, depending on the information in the first columns. The Data is stored in an Access Table. The Excel Worksheet, which has to be filled, has 75 columns and 10000 rows.
Right now, I am running a loop through all rows in the Excel Worksheet, getting the information from the first columns, running an SQL to select the necessary data from the Access Table and store it into an array.
The process is very fast, but after selecting the necessary information it takes a long time (maybe 0.5 seconds) to write the information from the array into the specific Excel Cell.

I am using the following code to write the information into the cell:

`objWS.Cells(Row, 13 + Array_Destination(z)) = Array_Columns(0, i)`

`objWS` = Excel Worksheet the information has be filled in.

`Row` = the rows which is looped through

`Array_Destination(z)` = the destination column is derived from this array

`Array_Columns` = this array contains the information to be filled into different columns in the objWS

Right now, the process can take up to 60 min.
Is there a faster way to write the information from the array into the cell?
I appreciate your help, Thank you!

I thought about pasting each array into several cells or a range in the Excel Worksheet. This won't work because I have to check every cell for some conditions, e.g. is the cell already filled.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using.

Comment: Copying 1000 values from array/cell elements to cell one-by-one takes  total 0.1 sec. on a very old machine. (ScreenUpdating and Calculation on.)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values into the spreadsheet cell by cell - you can do this an entire range at a time or a column at a time - e.g. by extracting a single dimension array from your array of columns and just doing something like `objWS.Range("A:A").Value = ArrColumn(0)`

If the 75 columns you are filling in are contiguous then adjust your SQL query to get all of the data in a single hit, into a single array and just assign the Range.Value to that array instead.

Also remember to turn off Application.ScreenUpdating and set Calculation to manual while you are doing the update

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!

I already turned off ScrrenUpdating and Calculations.

The 75 columns are contiguous but there are several conditions i have to check for each cell, since the date source is not very good (this problem cant be solved). I need to check the destination cell for background colour, already filled with a value or formula etc.
Therefore, pasting an array into a range will overwrite anything and won't let me test for those conditions.

Do you have any idea to bypass this problem?

Comment: If that was me I would merge the query from the Access Database with a query of the existing data and apply the validations in a Power Query - not for Background colour which woudl be unaffected by assigning a value to the cell.
Perhaps if you posted your actual code we could enhance it for performance

Comment: Putting an array of values into a range will only change the values in the range, it won't alter formatting.